# Issue when selecting a parent option in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select-nested-group (react-select now) for selecting nested options. But the issue i am facing is that when I select a parent option it only returns the parent option and the option does not get checked in the drop down. In case of selecting all the children of that option it works fine. Here is the object i am using for options .

```
[
{
    "label": "AUXO",
    "value": "5e2ea0969dde260f7eec5c3b",
    "options": [
        {
            "label": "Patrolling",
            "value": "5fb4bfba5a40c28eb7932091",
            "options": [
                {
                    "label": "c1",
                    "value": "601a7c3d9bd1684e9d20bc1a",
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "label": "test 1",
                            "value": "606ff36a90264f8993266696"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "c2",
                    "value": "606ee1c190264f8993266690"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "General",
            "value": "5fb4bfd15a40c28eb7932093",
            "options": [
                {
                    "label": "g1",
                    "value": "606ee1d190264f8993266692"
                },
                {
                    "label": "g2",
                    "value": "606ee1dc90264f8993266694"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Ahmed Hassan",
            "value": "60263baf132415067bd03f54"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

And the component is like this :

```
 <Select
    name={props.name}
    placeholder={props.placeholder || "Search..."}
    isMulti={props.multi || false}
    isClearable={props.clearable || true}
    isSearchable={props.searchable || true}
    isDisabled={props.disabled !== undefined ? props.disabled : false}
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    filterOption={createFilter(filterConfig)}
    value={state.preSelected}
    options={state.options}
    components={{ Option, GroupHeading, Group, ValueContainer }}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
```

For example on selecting Patrolling it expected output should be

```
[
{
    "label": "Patrolling",
    "value": "5fb4bfba5a40c28eb7932091"
},
{
    "label": "c1",
    "value": "601a7c3d9bd1684e9d20bc1a"
},
{
    "label": "test 1",
    "value": "606ff36a90264f8993266696"
},
{
    "label": "c2",
    "value": "606ee1c190264f8993266690"
}
]
```

But in my case it return only

```
{
    "label": "Patrolling",
    "value": "5fb4bfba5a40c28eb7932091"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the values you want to receive under the value key. For example:

```
const options = [
  { value: {/* Here goes everything you want to receive when selecting 'Option 1'. 
             You can out the whole object here  */}, label: 'Option 1' },
        ]
```